# Select any node in the DOM matching term

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I use xpath library. I use this instruction to select any table in DOM, but i get only the first table. For example:

```
load_structure('C:/example.html', DOM, []) 
xpath(DOM, //table, TB)
```

In example.html there are several tables, but i get only the first table. Why? How can i do to get all tables in the HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
...,
load_structure('C:/example.html', DOM, []) 
forall(xpath(DOM, //table, TB), use_table(TB)),
...
```

use_table/1 should not fail, or the entire loop will fail as well.

*edit*: to collect all tables:

```
findall(TB, xpath(DOM, //table, TB), Tables)
```